# When using parallel producer-consumer pattern, how let consumer know if producer caught exception?

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

In the code below producer is started in separate thread, and adding some items to `ConcurrentQueue<T>` queue . Consumer consists of `while(true)` loop and is trying to dequeue items from queue all the time.
When producer is finished  - it is raising `producerFinished` event flag, so that Consumer can detect that and exit infinite loop.
The problem occurs when Producer catches exception - it can't raise `producerFinished` event flag, and Consumer is stuck forever.
Can you recommend some solution on how Consumer can detect if Producer caught exception?

```
public override async Task SendMultiSkuSpmRequests(SpmRequestMultiSku hostRequest,
    IServerStreamWriter<SpmResponse> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
    ConcurrentQueue<SpmResponse> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<SpmResponse>();
    ManualResetEvent producerFinished = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => EnqueueSpmResponsesForMultiSku(hostRequest, queue, producerFinished));

    logger.Debug($"Starting to monitor Spm response queue, and will send them one by one via stream back to test Host.");
    while (true)
    {
        SpmResponse response;
        while (queue.Any())
        {
            queue.TryDequeue(out response);
            logger.Debug($"Sending Spm response back to client.");
            await responseStream.WriteAsync(response);
        }

        if (producerFinished.WaitOne(50))
        {
            logger.Debug($"Producer is finished and queue is empty - will exit the while(true) loop");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't raise producerFinished in Producer catch?

Comment: Take a look at the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) and [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) classes. They can make your life easier. The one is synchronous and the other is asynchronous.

Comment: Theodor, I'm familiar with BlockingCollection<T> - ConcurrentQeuue<T> that I'm using here is similar. Looked at Channel<T> - seems like it has much more options, but it still won't let me solve  Producer exception issue.

Comment: MichaelMao,  I thought about this - it means that in each try-catch I need to raise the flag, or do a try-catch on entire method , that is quite big.  I guess it would probably work. I was thinking maybe there is some kind of generic solution for this problem

Comment: The `Channel<T>` allows the propagation of an error with [`channel.Writer.Complete(error)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.complete).